# Issue with Profile Page Title "User Midhun MP - Stack Overflow"

Tags: bug, status-completed, profile-page, title, winter-bash-2013

In Stack Overflow, when I navigate to Profile page using Winter bash icon. It shows the URL on title instead of normal title (`User Midhun MP - Stack Overflow`).

In normal case, Title:

[image: Normal Case]

When I Navigate to Profile Page by clicking on Winter Bash Cap, title:

[image: Issue]

Comment: Can't reproduce in Chrome, maybe Firefox-only issue?

Comment: @balpha wow that was fast!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Good catch, thanks.  Fixed now.

Comment: Thanks for the fix, wow it was really fast :)